# Examples of ODEs with complex constant coefficients and applications to physics?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, physics, mathematical-modeling

This question is asked on stackexchange: [Are there examples for ODEs with complex coefficients with applications in physics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519278/are-there-examples-for-odes-with-complex-coefficients-with-applications-in-physi)
but received no answers. I am reposting it here on the hope that it catches the eye of some expert.

Question:

I have stumbled upon this paper
[Jung and Roh - The linear differential equations with complex constant coefficients and Schrödinger equations](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aml.2016.11.003).

It made me wonder:

Are there examples for ordinary differential equations with complex coefficients that have applications in physics? A reference or link would be very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A standard/classic example is a model for [tippe top inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tippe_top).  This model is a linear ODE with constant complex coefficients: $$
\ddot{z} + i \alpha \dot{z} + \beta \dot{z} + i \gamma z + \delta z = 0
$$
where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are real constants.  The complex $i \alpha \dot{z}$ term arises from Coriolis effects while the complex $i \gamma z$ term arises from damping in rotational variables.

Remarkably, these equations describe both (i) the  stability/instability of the inverted/noninverted states of the tippe top; and (ii) the existence of a heteroclinic connection between these states —- as illustrated below.

[image]

To read more about this connection, see Section 2 of [Dissipation-Induced
Heteroclinic Orbits in Tippe Tops](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/10958/1/BOUsiamr08.pdf).

For an animation  [click here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/suppl/10.1137/030601351/suppl_file/60135_01.mpg).